# How to iteratively rename files in Bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to iterate over files in a folder, renaming them as `foldername1`, `foldername2`, etc. However, I'm getting an error which says that the `mv` isn't being used correctly.

So far my code looks like this:

```
FILES='(Full Path)/Macbeth/audio/'
for file in "$FILES"*
do
    mv $file 'Macbeth'$i''
done
```

The final code should iterate through the files and rename them as, in this case `Macbeth1.mp3`, but I'm not sure how the Bash syntax works.

Comment: That means you don't have any such files.

Comment: I suggest to use absolute path and no relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Cyrus, the solution was to use the full path